# How to return an array from a function in PHP?

Tags: php, return

When I dump the array just before the return statement all seems good.
However, when I dump the result it seems empty.

Should be more clear with the code included. I call GetRow from DatabaseHandler, I can see there is an array when I make a dump before the return. (see the var_dump)

```
public static function GetRow($sqlQuery, $params = null,
                            $fetchStyle = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
 {
// Initialize the return value to null
$result = null;

// Try to execute an SQL query or a stored procedure
try
{
  // Get the database handler
  $database_handler = self::GetHandler();

  // Prepare the query for execution
  $statement_handler = $database_handler->prepare($sqlQuery);

  // Execute the query
  $statement_handler->execute($params);

  // Fetch result
  $result = $statement_handler->fetch($fetchStyle);
}
// Trigger an error if an exception was thrown when executing the SQL query
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  // Close the database handler and trigger an error
  self::Close();
  trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
}

// Return the query results
  exit(var_dump($result)); // SHOWS A PROPER ARRAY
return $result;
}
```

In the other function which calls it, there is nothing to be seen (false):

```
// Gets the details of a specific order
public static function GetOrderInfo($orderId)
{
// Build the SQL query
$sql = 'CALL orders_get_order_info(:order_id)';

// Build the parameters array
$params = array (':order_id' => $orderId);

// Execute the query and return the results
  $result = DatabaseHandler::GetRow($sql, $params);
  exit(var_dump($result)); // SHOWS FALSE
  return $result
}
```

Comment: Don't `exit` it never `return`s...

Comment: Use return after var_dump and remove exit.

Comment: this should be marked off as a typo

Comment: `exit(var_dump($result));` will show you the return value of the `var_dump(...)` (which, [as shown in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php), is nothing). It will not show you the same thing as, say, `var_dump($result); exit();`.

Comment: Thanks, but the dumps were just there to show what was in the variables. If I remove all exit statements, $result is just false

Comment: $result = false generally just means your query didn't return any rows.

Comment: Is it possible that it is simply $statement_handler->fetch($fetchStyle) returning false?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it, when I do a exit(var_dump($result)); just before the return statement I get a full array:
array(15) { ["customer_id"]=> string(2) "27" ["name"]=> string(15) "Laurens" ["email"]=> string(24) ......

Answer (score 0):

From the docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php:

> Terminates execution of the script

In other words, the `return` statement is unreacheable. So your code never returns because the process exits before it.

Comment: Thanks, but the dumps were just there to show what was in the variables. If I remove all exit statements, $result is just false

Comment: It's probably because you have a issue with your database or SQL. This statement return false: `$statement_handler->fetch($fetchStyle)` and that is the place to dig more.

Comment: When I dump it like this;
$result = $statement_handler->fetch($fetchStyle);
exit(var_dump($result));

I get to see the array.

Comment: Very strange, when I do this just before the return it works:

    $array['customer_id'] = $result['customer_id'];
    $array['shipping_region_id'] = $result['shipping_region_id'];
    $array['credit_card'] = $result['credit_card'];

    return $array;

Comment: The `var_dump($result)` shows an array or a object?

Comment: var_dump(is_array($result)) shows true, and when I dump it I see an array like my comment above.

Strangely enough, I can't use this array in a foreach. It says 'invalid argument'.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call exit.  There's nothing special about arrays in PHP in terms of arguments/return values - the problem is that you're terminating with the exit() call.

Comment: Thanks, but the dumps were just there to show what was in the variables. If I remove all exit statements, $result is just false.

Answer (score -1):

While PDO returned an Array, it was unusable for functions like foreach, while, or json_encode (invalid argument).

The solutions was to use MySQLi, it returned exactly the same Array, only this time it was usable for functions like foreach, while, or json_encode.